# Adding Proxy for Android Things

Tags: android, networking, proxy, android-things

How to add proxy for Android things.
I am now running on androidthings dp7 on raspberry pi 3.
Connected to internet using  ethernet where  the android things board is behind the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now this feature is not available with things os

A ticket is in pending at developer end
We should wait till they include this feature in android things OS